# JavaScript Replace issues

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an array of objects that have 2 properties: Key and Value.  I have a block of text with placeholders that correspond to the object Keys.  I want to replace the placeholders with the corresponding Value from the object with the matching key.

I have the following code:

```
function LoadReplacementData(replacementData)
{
    var text = $("#textblock").html();

    $.each(replacementData, function(index, item)
    {
        var expression = new RegExp("\[sub:" + item.Key + "\]", "g");
        text = text.replace(expression, item.Value);
    });

    $("#textblock").html(text);
}
```

I have tested the pattern over at RegExLib.com under JavaScript and it comes back with all instances of the placeholders which are in the form of "[sub:KeyText]".  I have also ensured the Keys and Values are coming back properly.  I have also looped through the various expressions that are generated and the resulting patterns are accurate.

The above code results in an "Out of Memory Exception" at the line of `text = text...`  If I remove the assignment, nothing happens.

Any idea where I'm going wrong to do this replacement?

Comment: How big is the inner html for `#textblock`?

Comment: Why regular expression and not simple replace in this case?

Comment: I think replace will only replace one instance, not all.

Comment: Does it still happen if you replace the each iterator with a plain for loop?

Comment: @tj111 Less than 2000 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing i see is that you're not escaping your backslashes.

```
var expression = new RegExp("\\[sub:" + item.Key + "\\]", "g");
```

Comment: @EFraim True but it is still a JavaScript string and needs to be escaped prior to being converted into a pattern.

Comment: After I escaped the back slashes in the string so that the pattern would see it as a single backslash, it resolved the issue.

Comment: And you propose using a regex for single replace all?

Answer (score 3):

What about using join and split to prevent memory errors? It will significantly save on memory overhead as it doesn't have to parse the entire string multiple times using a regular expression, just a standard string method.

```
text = text.split("[sub:"+item.Key+"]").join(item.Value)
```